# Installing Skype is not working: "unable to locate package Skype"

Tags: software-installation, skype

I'm desperate, I've tried everything. I can't install Skype no matter what. I've tried every command I could and still nothing. When I download from the website I get a read only folder.

Whatever command I use, this is the result

```
Unable to locate package Skype
```

Answer (score 6):

Open a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdebi
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo gdebi skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

This should do it. If the system tells you that `gdebi` is already installed you can ignore this and simply continue with the next command.

Comment: This worked but now I can't even get ubuntu to load/boot properly. I have to go system recovery and boot normally from there otherwise my laptop just shuts down before Ubuntu even loads. So f****** frustrating.

Comment: That should not be caused by this, did you have some other updates running lately?

Comment: I just factory reset everything and it seems to be working again. In terms of updates no nothing other than sudo apt update.  I literally didn't install anything else or do anything else to it. I'm wondering if there was some conflict between gdebi and ubuntu software.

Comment: Should not be a conflict between them, they are completely independent.

Answer (score 2):

Have you downloaded the latest version from official website: https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/ ?

You can download the .deb file and open it with UBUNTU software center then click install.

If it does not work please reply with more details.