# Ubuntu 16.04 skype upgrade 5.x to 8.x

Tags: skype

I have error: "Sorry, this version of Skype is not supported anymore."

How i can upgrade skype 5.x to 8.x?

Comment: Just download new version from [skype.com](https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb). It will auto-update.

Comment: Just follow my answer here and you're set... https://askubuntu.com/q/984425 given you use a 64 bit system.

Comment: i dont wont install or re-install, I wonna make an upgrade 1 action in the terminal

Comment: @ultimatum: Jokes aside, please have a look at the top answer of the linked question. The "upgrade" is literally 3 shell commands if you want to use the terminal and don't have the Skype repository added to Apt (which Skype 5 should have done for you). DPKG (and thus Apt) doesn't distinguish between package upgrades and re-installations.

Comment: Beside installing the new Skype with the method i described sets it up for normal updates.

Comment: @Videonauth: So does the top answer of the linked question as explained in it.

Comment: thanks everyone!

sudo apt-get -y remove skypeforlinux --purge && wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb && sudo dpkg -i skypeforlin*.deb 

its work